# Using pandas string selection after sort_index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I can't figure out why un-commenting `ts = ts.sort_index()` in the code below throws an ErrorKey:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [2, 1, 3],
    'd': [
        datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 21),
        datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 20),
        datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 22)
    ]
})

ts = df.set_index('d')
#ts = ts.sort_index()

ts['2018-05-21']
```

My assumption is that `sort_index` in some ways generates a new index and therefore breaks the string selection but I can't find any evidence of it.

To provide some context, I want to sort this time series in order to select a time range (e.g., `ts['2018-05-21':]`). If I don't sort it, it works for the example above but not for the time range.

Comment: I'm going to venture a guess and say this is a bug. But the fact is you should be using `loc` to begin with, so you can't really blame pandas for not handling edge cases it really shouldn't need to.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend using `.loc`

```
#ts = df.set_index('d')
#ts = ts.sort_index()
ts.loc['2018-05-21':,:]
Out[102]: 
            x
d            
2018-05-21  2
2018-05-22  3
```

Comment: Yup, this is the right way. *But* the behaviour OP finds still seems strange to me. Would be great to know why sorting matters.

Comment: @RafaelC try with ts['2018-05-21']

Comment: Yep, this is the funny behavior. It interprets the string as a column rather than the intended dt index - but adding `:` changes everything e.g. `ts['2018-05-21':'2018-05-21']`. Tbh idk why